# How can I find glass cutting patents?

Tags: patents

How can I find glass cutting patents? Apparently they use a different numbering system than ordinary patents. For example, according to glass collectors, the following patent was registered:

```
63,795 / “Exotic Flower” / William P. Moran / 18 Jan 1923 / 15 Jan 1924
```

However, U.S. patent 63795 does not correspond to this patent.

Comment: https://patents.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Try it before recommending it. Type in US63795 and see if the patent I listed above appears.

Comment: US Patent [63795 is a table knife](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/5b/e9/8a/c8f9d9e60c5ca1/US63795.pdf), so I'm guessing the reference you found, which I'm guessing is from [this page](https://www.brilliantglass.com/clark/) is not valid. Furthermore, there are no patents by William P Moran (well, there are, but they are from the 1990's). When doing patent searches, I find that https://patents.google.com is a good resource.

Comment: Searching for one of them (16720 “Strawberry Diamond and Star”) I get exactly 3 websites, that seem to quote one another. Sure that it is a patent and not a misquote where someone took Pat as Patent instead of *pattern*? And sure it is even a US patent? I am quite sure that you can't patent a non functional pattern...

Comment: @Trish Cut glass collectors are never wrong :-) There is some nuance here that is being missed. I don't know what it is, but that is why I am asking the legal forum, because you guys are supposed to experts in things like intellectual property law.

Comment: @Cicero Where, exactly, did you come up with that (mistaken) idea?

Comment: @Trish - In the U.S., Japan and some other places you can patent a non-functional design as a design patent

Comment: @GeorgeWhite which, as the answer shows, is distinct from a normal [utility] patent

Answer (score 3):

The reason why I could not find the patent is that there are several different kinds of patents. Mechanical patents, for example, are "utility" patents. The cut glass pattern referenced in the question is not a utility patent, it is a design patent. Each patent type has its own numbering system. To search for a design patent, typically a "D" is inserted before the patent number, like "D63795". This results in the correct patent being discovered:

[image]

Comment: So, it's a misquote - missing the D

Comment: In the U.S. their are only three kinds of patents. Utility, Design and Plant.

Comment: @Trish The glass collectors assume that the reader is experienced enough to know that a design patent is being referenced. I did not have that experience and obviously neither did you.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That's my goal in life: to patent a plant.